# Bootstrap 3 Active Menu State Colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This may be simple, however I can't seem to accomplish what I need.

Basically, I want the colour to change to something else rather than bootstrap's default blue when the page in question is in active.

I have tried many different css, but this is my current:

```
ul.nav a:active { 
    background-color: #3366CC !important;  
}
```

The navbar that im using is as followed:

```
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified fixed-top">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
```

etc

Is there a simple CSS rule that I'm missing, the colours change quite freely for my other menu needs, such as:

```
ul.nav  {
    padding: 5px;
}

ul.nav li a {
    color: #fff;
}

ul.nav li a:hover{
    color: #CC0033 !important;
}

ul.nav a:hover { 
    background-color: #fff !important; 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would shy away from using `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the color to the a tag inside the li with the active class

```
ul.nav li.active a { 
    background-color: #3366CC !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The :active pseudo-class only matches when, for example, the user is in the process of clicking on the link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active
It does not indicate which page is active.

In Bootstrap the page/section that is currently active is signaled by an *active* class on the *li*. In Bootstrap 3, try:

```
.nav > .active { 
    background-color: #3366CC;  
}
```

Use Inspect Element to find out what style is actually being applied, so you can properly override it.